# Serial port comms only working in one direction

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port

I am working with a SOM mounted on a carrier board running Ubuntu 14.04 with the generic 3.13 kernel.

While testing out the peripherals, I hit a problem with serial communication.

Basically, I can transmit data from the custom platform to an external Linux machine, but I can not properly receive data from the external Linux machine to the custom platform.

Through my research I have messed with all sorts of BIOS settings, baud rates, hardware flow control, parity, etc. Nothing has worked. Most info I have found online just says "Make sure your baud rates and other settings match", and they do. It is not my first time working with Linux serial ports. But it is my first time encountering a problem like this.

**Does anyone have any suggestions, recommendations, or has anyone ever seen an issue like this before?**

More info: We are running a quad-core Intel Atom micro with a custom serial breakout interface. The serial port is at /dev/ttyS0.

EDIT (clarification):
If I set up a session in Picocom or Minicom, I can send characters from our custom platform (running Ubuntu 14.04) to another Linux PC (also running Ubuntu 14.04). However, if I try to send characters from the Linux PC to our custom board, I sometimes get nothing, and other times get unrecognized characters (they show up as bubbles with question marks in them).

I can also simply echo a string to /dev/ttyS0 on the custom platform and receive it on the Linux PC. I just can't get it to work the other way around.

Comment: "receive data from the external Linux machine to the custom platform" means what? "not properly" means "somehow, but not quite right"?

Comment: I added a clarification, hopefully that helps.

Comment: "bubbles with question marks" - exactly one per sent character, or does the number vary?

Comment: Exactly one per character. They only show up when using picocom. minicom just shows nothing.

Comment: I think your problem is signal level on the TxD line not high enough for the RxD Input on the incorrectly receiving side.

Comment: Alright, I'll get out the scope and see what I find then get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you connect the TX RX on your board together, do you receive the characters you expect?

Comment: I traced it down to the TI MAX232 part on the custom board. I put a scope on the Tx and Rx lines coming from the Linux box and the levels looked fine. I then looked at the Tx and Rx lines from the MAX232 part to the custom SOM and the Rx line stayed low. So it looked like the MAX232 part was not properly translating the signal level on the Rx line to the custom board.